# XMLExeption Root Element missing while saving user data

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, cocos2d-x

I have a problem with saving user data in my Android App.

For a while everything was fine with the code:

```
CCUserDefault.SharedUserDefault.SetIntegerForKey("score", score);
                    CCUserDefault.SharedUserDefault.Flush();
```

I don't know why, because I didn't change anything in this class but now I get an XML Exeption with the Text: **Root Element is missing**.

I opened the Instance if the Exaption but there is no Information. Only LineNumber 0 and LinePosition 0 and an empty SourceUri.

I just want so save the Highscore, which XML he means? Is the Data saved in a XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself, here's the solution.

The data is saved in a XML File and if you changed your Key the **"Root Element is missing"**. So delete the Cache and local Data on your Emulator or Device and the problem is fixed.